# What versions of Java will support TLS1.1

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

*What versions of Java will support TLS1.1*
I just need the exact java version and update like **JDK 7uXX**

Reason for this question I am facing an issue connecting TLS1.1 with Java 1.7 . In most of the document I have read its supports but we have to enabled it manually. Even though its not working  after enabling.

While googled I Got information like it will work only with  java 7u95.

FYI 
*Java JDK does not enable TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2 by default in clients: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#tlsprotonote
jdk.tls.client.protocols system property has been introduced to allow controlling the underlying platform TLS implementation and enabling specific protocols on the client. This system property is available in all JDK 8 releases, or after Java 7 update 95 (January 2016) and Java 6 update 121 (July 2016). Example of use: -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2*

Link : http://communities.rightnow.com/posts/cb48420cb0

Comment: is this really that hard to look up yourself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming.

Comment: Thanks for the response, just now I completed full query.

Answer (score 0):

All JDK7 versions support TLS1.1
For JDK6 (2006 to end of public updates 2013) : TLS v1.1 (JDK 6 update 111 and above)

Comment: In my server environment I need to stick JDK 7u45, I tried its not working with TLS 1.1 whereas I am testing the same with Java 1.8 its working fine