# 1.7 the code works fine, but in 1.6 it breaks with handshake error

Tags: java, ssl, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to call soap API in JAVA with SSL, java 1.7 is working but 1.6 is not working.

I am geting: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

why with java 1.7 works but with 1.6 does not work ?

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SoapUI (1)\\SoapUI\\x.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "passX!");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");



URL u = null;
try {
    u = new URL("https://x1/x2WS/x3?wsdl");
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
JobInput2Service service = new JobInput2Service(u);
JobInput2 job = service.getJobInput2Port();
try {
    HelloRequestParm parm = new HelloRequestParm();
    parm.setMessage("value");
    HelloResponseData res = job.sayHello(parm);
    System.out.print("\n res: "+res.getMessage());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104761/what-versions-of-java-will-support-tls1-1

Comment: But one should also ask: why are you using Java 6 or Java 7 to run web stuff?  Both are EOL!

Comment: I have no choice

Comment: I set the parameter to use TLSv1

Comment: Whoever gave you no choice has no choice but to upgrade.

Comment: Exactly which Java 1.6? Sun/Oracle? free (through 6u45) or paid (higher)? OpenJDK? IBM? Apple? Android? Could be SNI; can you test connecting (only connecting, no data) with `openssl s_client` with and without `-servername $host` <= 1.1.0 or `-noservername` in 1.1.1? Can you run with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` and capture the output?

Comment: *I have no choice*  Are the fools who aren't giving you a choice aware that Java 1.6 is hopelessly insecure?  Assuming you're running 1.6.0_45 - the last publicly-available version of Java 1.6, [this is a list](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/javacpujun2013-1899847.html#AppendixJAVA) of vulnerabilities in Java 1.6.0_u45 that Oracle patched **6 years ago**.  Note the **eleven 10.0 vulnerabilities** out of ~40 fixed there that are easy to exploit remotely and **completely** compromise any security on your system.  Again - those mandating you stay on Java 1.6 are **fools**.

Comment: [Here's the list fixed **four** years ago.](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpujan2015-1972971.html#AppendixJAVA)  There are **four more 10s** on that list that exist in Java 1.6.  Four more easy-to-exploit remove vulnerabilities in Java that Oracle fixed **four years ago** that still exist in your Java version.  Is your management aware of **that**?  How about the **owners**?  That's **fifteen** 10.0-severity vulnerabilities that were fixed an average of half a decade ago, found in just two random samplings.

Comment: [And we're now up to **eighteen extant 10.0 vulnerabilities** in Java 1.6.0_45](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpuapr2015-2365600.html#AppendixJAVA) in just three Oracle patch listings, randomly selected from the past six years.

Answer (score 1):

According to the references below, Java 6.0 (all versions) support TLS 1.0.

Now it apparently isn't working for you, and it looks like you are using the correct property value.  I suspect that the problem is that you are setting the networking properties in the system properties object *too late* for them to have any effect.  Try setting them using `-Dname=value` command line properties instead.

If you set system properties programatically, you need to do it before they are used.  The network properties are typically used when static initialization is triggered, and that is often earlier than you think in an application's life-cycle.

However, there is one thing that is bothering me.  According to one of those references, TLS 1.0 is the default for Java 6.0.  If that is correct, it should not be necessary to set the "https.protocols" at all to get TLS 1.0.  So, if my suggestion above doesn't work, the next step should be to add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and look at the log messages produced when you attempt to establish an HTTPS connection.

References:

- ["Transport Level Security (TLS) and Java"](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/tls-and-java/)
- ["Diagnosing TLS, SSL, and HTTPS"](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https)

---

You should share the following with your management and customers:

- You / they should not be using Java 6 or Java 7 ... unless you / they have an Oracle Java support contract and are using a recent non-public release.  Public releases of Java 6 or Java 7 are EOL.  Java 6 has been EOL since April 2013.  That's a **lot** of security fixes you are missing!
- You / they should not be using TLS 1.0.  It is no longer considered secure.  One [source](https://www.howsmyssl.com/s/about.html) says this:

  > *"TLS 1.0 is the first version of TLS, is fairly common in the world, and requires workarounds in both the client and server to work securely for all cipher suites. TLS 1.0 is also unable to use modern cipher suites that offer greater security and efficiency."*